# In C#, what is the most elegant way to merge items in an array are part of a "single larger item"?

Tags: c#, collections, merge

I have a C# app and I am pulling data from an external tracking system that tracks people requests and I store them in my database.  So something like this:

```
public class Request
{
   public DateTime Start {get;set;}
   public DateTime End {get;set;}
   public int PersonId {get;set;}
} 

IEnumerable<Request> requests = GetExternalRequests();
```

The details of GetExternalRequests() are not relevant to the question.

The issue is that the service breaks things down to send me a request for every individual day (even if the request is a multi day request)

For example, if a person puts in a request for a full week (Monday to Friday), I get 5 different items in the array (each with a single date) and I would like to "merge" those into a single request with Start = Monday and End = Friday to avoid saving 5 different records into my database.

So far, I have what feels like a pretty inelegant solution now where I loop through all of the requests and put the results in a dictionary and then run the code below

```
IEnumerable<Request> requests = GetExternalRequests();

IEnumerable<Request> previousRequests = GetAllPreviousRequests();

Dictionary<string, Request> cachedDictionary = CacheAllRequestsByDateandPersonId(requests, previousRequests)

var groupedByPerson = requests.GroupBy(r=>r.PersonId);
foreach (var group in groupedByPerson)
{
    foreach (Request request in group.OrderBy(r=>r.StartDate) 
    {
         var offSet = 1;
         if (request.StartDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
         {
             offSet = 3;
         }
         if (cachedDictionary.ContainsKey(request.PersonId + request.StartDate.AddDays(offset))
         {
              //delete the request from the list and change the start date of the next request to the start date of this request.
         }
    }
}
```

so I wanted to get some suggestions to see if there is a more elegant way to "merge" these results.

To add some clarity (based on some comments below)

- Requests cannot overlap (think vacation requests)
- If I already have a previous request on Monday and a new request comes in on Tuesday then I also want to merge those

Comment: What is `MergeAlignedRequests`? - seems to be the method most relevant to the question? Also, is this merging all requests *before* inserting, or do you also want to merge existing requests? (For example, they make a request on Monday and then later make one for Tuesday as well?)

Comment: What type is `cacheRequest`?  Where's it assigned?

Comment: Is only the `Day` in `Request.Start` and `Request.End` relevant?

Comment: In general, can you make any assumption about `Request.Start` or `Request.End`? Could there be overlapped requests?

Comment: @Rob - that was a typo. I moved the function inline for the question

Comment: If you have some person that only have requests in Monday to Wednesday, will you mantain the 3 request?

Comment: @recursive - i have updated the question to make that explicit

Comment: @YacoubMassad - no, requests can not be overlapping

Comment: @Rob - I have updated to question to clarify

Comment: @leora: I still don't know type `cachedRequest` is.  BTW, did you intend to have two variables `cachedRequest` and `cachedDictionary`? In any case the types aren't obvious.

Comment: @recursive - looks like SOF lost my changes.  I have updated and saved again

Comment: The `Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TAccumulate seed, Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> func)` extension method will help. Make the seed an empty `List<Request>` and add new ones or modify the end dates of existing ones in the `func`.

Comment: @Alberto - in your example that would also be merged into a single request . . Any multiday request should be merged

Comment: @leora I answered, it fits your need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your GetExternalRequests return some seed data like that

```
private static IEnumerable<Request> GetExternalRequests()
{
    yield return new Request(new DateTime(2015, 1, 4), new DateTime(2015, 1, 4), 1);
    yield return new Request(new DateTime(2015, 1, 5), new DateTime(2015, 1, 5), 1);
    yield return new Request(new DateTime(2015, 1, 6), new DateTime(2015, 1, 6), 1);
    yield return new Request(new DateTime(2015, 1, 7), new DateTime(2015, 1, 7), 1);
    yield return new Request(new DateTime(2015, 1, 8), new DateTime(2015, 1, 8), 1);

    yield return new Request(new DateTime(2015, 1, 11), new DateTime(2015, 1, 11), 1);
    yield return new Request(new DateTime(2015, 1, 15), new DateTime(2015, 1, 15), 1);

    yield return new Request(new DateTime(2015, 1, 19), new DateTime(2015, 1, 19), 1);

    yield return new Request(new DateTime(2015, 1, 26), new DateTime(2015, 1, 26), 1);

    yield return new Request(new DateTime(2015, 1, 4), new DateTime(2015, 1, 4), 2);
    yield return new Request(new DateTime(2015, 1, 7), new DateTime(2015, 1, 7), 2);
}
```

Then you can merge your data using GroupBy, and then Aggregate to merge consecutive days

See the code below:

```
private static IList<Request> MergeRequests(IEnumerable<Request> requests)
{
    return requests.GroupBy(r => r.PersonId)
                    .Aggregate(new Stack<Request>(), (list, grouping) =>
                    {
                        foreach (var request in grouping.OrderBy(r => r.StartDate))
                        {
                            var peek = list.Any() ? list.Peek() : null;
                            if (peek?.EndDate.Date.Day + 1 == request.StartDate.Date.Day)
                                peek.EndDate = request.EndDate;
                            else
                                list.Push(request);
                        }
                        return list;
                    })
                    .OrderBy(x => x.PersonId).ThenBy(x => x.StartDate)
                    .ToList();
}
```

So lets test this solution

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
    IEnumerable<Request> requests = GetExternalRequests();

    var requestsMerge = MergeRequests(requests);


    foreach (var request in requestsMerge)
        Console.WriteLine($"Person Id: {request.PersonId} - StartDate: {request.StartDate} - EndDate: {request.EndDate}");
}
```

The output data is that:

> Person Id: 1 - StartDate: 1/4/2015 12:00:00 AM - EndDate: 1/8/2015 12:00:00 AM
>
> Person Id: 1 - StartDate: 1/11/2015 12:00:00 AM - EndDate: 1/12/2015 12:00:00 AM
>
> Person Id: 1 - StartDate: 1/19/2015 12:00:00 AM - EndDate: 1/19/2015 12:00:00 AM
>
> Person Id: 1 - StartDate: 1/26/2015 12:00:00 AM - EndDate: 1/26/2015 12:00:00 AM
>
> Person Id: 2 - StartDate: 1/4/2015 12:00:00 AM - EndDate: 1/4/2015 12:00:00 AM
>
> Person Id: 2 - StartDate: 1/7/2015 12:00:00 AM - EndDate: 1/7/2015 12:00:00 AM

Comment: This will group non-contiguous requests - For example, they ask for `Monday` and `Friday`, it will select `Monday -> Friday`

Comment: @Rob He said that `If I already have a previous request on Monday and a new request comes in on Tuesday then I also want to merge those`

Comment: Well yes, but merging Monday and Tuesday is different from merging Monday and Friday. This code, if given Monday and Friday, will create a request for Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday Thursday *and* Friday.

Comment: @Rob did you saw seed data that I added? It doest have a example with one request in monday and another thursday, and my code return just one request for that.

Comment: @Rob Why two? It should only have one request, with startdate on monday and enddate in thursday

Comment: If you ask your boss for Monday and Thursday off, would you also not come in on Wednesday? :)

Comment: @Rob I guess we have wrong understanding about what leora wants. Btw I asked leora if there is a request on monday and another in thursday, they should me merged in one, leora said yes.

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro I misinterpreted your question. I only want to merge requests that are next to each other. So if there are 2 request one is Monday and one is Thursday I would NOT merge those.

Comment: @leora I fixed it now

Comment: @leora some feedback?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
public class Request
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Request(DateTime start)
    {
        while (!IsWorkingDay(start))
            start = start.AddDays(1);
        Start = start;

        End = start.AddDays(1);
        while (!IsWorkingDay(End))
            End = End.AddDays(1);
    }

    private bool IsWorkingDay(DateTime date)
    {
        return date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday;
    }

    public bool Intersects(Request otherRequest)
    {
        if (otherRequest == this)
            return true;

        return !(otherRequest.End < Start || otherRequest.Start > End);
    }

    public void Merge(Request otherRequest)
    {
        if (otherRequest.Start < Start)
            Start = otherRequest.Start;
        if (otherRequest.End > End)
            End = otherRequest.End;
    }
}
```

And use it as follows:

```
var requests = GetExternalRequests().ToList();

var result = requests.GroupBy(g => g.PersonId)
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy (r => r.Start)
    .Aggregate(new List<Request>(), 
        (acc, right) => {
        if (acc.Count > 0)
        {
            var lastItem = acc[acc.Count - 1];
            if (lastItem.Intersects(right))
            {
                lastItem.Merge(right);
                return acc;
            }
        }
        acc.Add(right);
        return acc;
    }));
```

The `Request` class itself should be responsible for things like expanding over the weekend. This ensures you can't have a broken request.

Answer (score 0):

`cachedDictionary.Contains` on a `Dictionary<T, T>` is a linq method, and it uses a brute force search.  That is definitely the slowest part of the algorithm.

I suggest a change to the contents of your inner loop.  Don't try to modify the requests in-place.  Rather, build a new list of requests that only creates a new request when a non-consecutive day is encountered in the inner loop.  The end of the request is set when the next request is started, or when the loop is complete.